# geb handing multiple tabs simultaneously

Tags: spock, geb

My testing environment is Geb+Spock.
I have one test case scenario in which I perform some operation(e.g.creating a user) in one tab[URL1] of chrome browser and after performing that operation I want to verify it on the other tab[URL2].

Both tab's URLs are different.

I have tried below approach but it didn't work:

```java
class checkUserSpec {
    def 'create new users'(){
        given:'URL of creating user page'
        browser.at(createUserPage)
    when:'create user'
        createUser()
    then:'User should be created'
        withNewWindow({js.exec("window.open(URL2', 'opennewtab', '')")} ,page:verifyUserPage, wait: true) { 
            at verifyUserPage
            verifyUserPage.with{
                verifyCreatedUser()
        }
    }
}
}
```

```java
class createUserPage {

  static URL = 'URL1'
  static at ={
        $(title: "Create User Page")
  }
    def createUser(){
    ......
    ......

    }
}
```

```java
class verifyUserPage {

static URL = 'URL2'
  static at ={
        $(title: "Verify User Page")
  }
    def verifyCreatedUser(){
    ......
    ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code with what you have tried so far?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Are you seeing some error or unexpected behaviour? Can you please describe it?

Comment: Your test code looks quite strange. How do you get to `createUserPage` in the first place? It is also incomplete, the "..." part is probably part of why it fails. I am also wondering why you would use JS in order to create a new tab and why you need the other tab at all. Why not just open the page in the existing tab with a normal `to SomePage`? BTW, nobody can just copy & paste your code because the spec is not a spec and the pages are not pages because they do not extend the respective base classes. This is just pseudo code. Do you want to make it harder on purpose for everyone to help you?